# BMC Remedy AR system API

Tags: python, python-3.x, remedy

I am trying to extract details from incident. I set:

```
entryListFields = [1000000161, 1000000217, 1000005781];
entry_result = arserver_user.getEntry (form，entry_info_list[0].getEntryID(entryListFields);
```

however，this `entry_result` returns not only the 3 data fields  requested, but also with these fields: `1, 30376000, 303524200, 303524300`.

and when I use `value = entry_result.get (1000000161);`

It returns “None”

Comment: could you add some more of the preceding code? it seems like something is missing... my gut tells me that you are not sending the entryListFileds which you are expecting. A side note: field 1 is always returned as far as i remember

Comment: There isn't a standard API for python. However your tag suggests you are using it. I would either use Java, at which I can point you in the right direction for the code, or use the REST interface if the Remedy version is more than 9.1. And then you can use Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Jython API, which is a Python wrapper for the AR Java API:

https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-19318

Here is some sample query code from that doc:

```
def get_entry():
    """This is how to return a single entry using the getEntry method
    """
    try:
        schema = 'User'  # We define our form here
        entry_id = '000000000000001'  # We define our target entry_id here
 
        # How to return an entry with all fields
        entry = ars.getEntry(schema, entry_id, None)
        print(entry)
 
        # How to return an entry with certain fields (Field ID 1,2,3,4,5 in this scenario)
        entry = ars.getEntry(schema, entry_id, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        print(entry)
 
        # How to loop through and print entry, accounting for null values w/ toString method
        entry = ars.getEntry(schema, entry_id, None)
        for i in entry:
            print '%s: %s' % (i, entry[i].toString())
    except ARException, e:
        print(e)
```